# Help Me with my SQL Query (Need it to always return at least one row.)

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, query-optimization, resultset

First off, here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT research_cost, tech_name,
    (SELECT research_cost
        FROM technologies
        WHERE research_cost <= USERS_RESEARCH_POINTS_VALUE
        ORDER BY research_cost DESC
        LIMIT 1) as research_prev,
    (SELECT cost
        FROM technology_costs
        WHERE id = 18
        LIMIT 1) as technology_cost
FROM `technologies`
    JOIN technology_costs
    ON id = COUNT_OF_TECHS_USER_LEARNED
WHERE research_cost > USERS_RESEARCH_POINTS_VALUE
ORDER BY research_cost ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Website link: http://www.joemajewski.com/fortress/

Some people might consider the above query to be moderate-sized, or even small; not me. For me, that's one of the largest and most complex SQL queries I've ever written, so I pushed myself to my limits.

Anyways, the query itself has no syntax errors, and it does exactly what I want it to do, for the most part. There's one minor issue, however.

If the main `SELECT` clause doesn't return a row (the "SELECT research_cost, tech_name FROM `technologies` WHERE research_cost > whatever"), then the entire query is an empty set.

If it helps, Fortress is this game that I'm working on. It's a browser-based MMORPG where users build an army to try and get a top stop in the leaderboards. Technologies are a game mechanic where users purchase upgrades to their stats (gold income, unit production, etc). Researching is a game mechanic that allows you to learn new technologies by training scientists to do the researching. That's what this query is all about. It grabs the current technology that is being researched, as well as the research cost of it. It additionally grabs the cost in gold of how much the next technology will cost.

So... is there any way that I can force at least a null row to be returned in the result set, as the nested select statements retrieve variables that I need in the script, even if the outer query returns nothing. Or could someone possibly change it around so that a result is always returned.

If anything else is needed, let me know. :)

Comment: What should the "default" row return?

Comment: Have you tried INNER JOIN instead of JOIN? Just a thought...

Comment: @Benny..  join = inner join.  it's implied.

Comment: I am trying to understand what it is you are trying to retrieve from the database. It appears you want the most expensive technology the user already has, and the cost of that technology, and the cheapest technology the user doesn't have, and the cost of that. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Joe, it'd be awesome if you started using table aliases.  I'd like to know the connection between technologies and technology_costs and which fields are coming from where.  I like the UNION query answer below, but I was going to write a large query with CASE statements.

Comment: @Benny I tried all different types of joins that I could think of and none of them made a difference. @Fosco: I never knew that either. Thanks for the info. :) @Brian: I am trying to retrieve the cost of the next technology (i have a costs table where the first tech costs 200, then 300, 500, etc...). I am also retrieving the research costs for the current and next technology. So if the current tech requires 1000 points and the next tech 3000, then (3000 - 1000 = 2000) I can calculate the amount of research needed from the current to the next (if that makes any sense). I also grab the tech name

Comment: Yeah, I should have added aliases to this query. I have a few queries where I was forced to use aliases because I was using ambiguous fields, but I should try to get into the habit you suggested.

Comment: @Patrick: When my query is returning an empty set, I'd like for it to return NULL for the research_cost and tech_name, and correct values for everything else. But instead of doing that, it doesn't get any result.

Comment: I'd consider going with the solution suggested by @a1ex07, only using your subqueries for the research_prev and technology cost columns instead of NULL. (The query after the union should go against table/set that always returns one row.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This query always returns at least 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM (__your old query__)aaa
UNION 
SELECT NULL as research_cost, NULL as tech_name, NULL as research_prev, 
... etc [FROM DUAL] // DUAL is a  dummy table in mysql
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works exactly. I've never used union before so this is all new syntax for me.

Comment: Your original query remains untouched, `SELECT * FROM (your_query)aaa` is used just to make sure your limit and ordery by clause applied. Then we union this result with  `SELECT NULL, NULL, ...` This query doesn't have `FROM` clause, and it always returns exactly one row (NULL,NULL,NULL, etc). As far as I understood your question it will work for you. All you need in client-side  is to ignore the record with all fields equal NULL.

Comment: You should maybe show the FROM clause for the second query...unless MySQL is like SQL Server and you don't always need one.

Comment: Weird, that "FROM DUAL" thing. I get no error with this new query, but no result set either. Doesn't even say "empty set".

Answer (score 6):

An approach that does not require a second select that lists every original column:

```
SELECT yourstuff.*
FROM (__your original query__) yourstuff
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS fake FROM DUAL) faketable ON 1=1;
```

If your original query returns any rows, they are passed through unaffected.  If it returns no rows, you will get one row of all nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I would try wrapping it in ISNULL()

Like this:

```
SELECT research_cost, tech_name, 
ISNULL((SELECT research_cost 
    FROM technologies 
    WHERE research_cost <= USERS_RESEARCH_POINTS_VALUE 
    ORDER BY research_cost DESC 
    LIMIT 1), 0.00) as research_prev, 
    [the rest of your query here]

//Note: instead of '0.00' you'll want some appropriate default value.
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  It's not the inner queries that are coming back without results, it's the main query.

Comment: @Fosco - You're right.  I did misread.  I'll leave this here for a few minutes (to document my shame) and then delete.

Comment: @Fosco: Yeah, that's correct. Anyways, I've never heard of the ISNULL() function before, so thanks for the tip. I think the syntax that I was using may have been incorrect because I tested it out and it failed.

Comment: Hi Joe.. how about throwing a closed beta promo code my way? gfosco@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting an empty row with the proper schema first, then try filling those rows in with the query you wrote above. The only downside is the additional query to do so.

That way, if your query above returns nothing, you still have the empty row and you can check on that.

Comment: The reason I'm doing it this way in the first place is to reduce the amount of queries. I could have one extra simply query and the problem would be solved, but I'm optimizing at the moment. Thanks for the suggestion though.