# Expanding on SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I created a query that is checking for "friend relations". Basically, `friend_one`/`$user_id` is the user signed in and `friend_two`/`$profile_user` is the other user's id... ie: If I clicked on another user's profile on here, it is that user.

My system works fine, except for when the logged in user looks at their own profile. Since my query is checking for the logged in user viewing another profile, it throws undefined variable errors when the logged in user views their own profile.

Is there anything I can do to my `SQL` or `php` that I can change so when `friend_one` / `user_id` views there own profile that it doesn't throw unrecognized variable errors?

The first unrecognized variable error starts here: `if ($friend_status == 2) {`. So the query doesn't throw an error.

Errors are showing because I will never have a user have relation with themselves in this table. So, I guess this error will occur when viewing "unfriended" profiles as well. Any ideas of a way to fix it?

---

EDIT:

My original answer was a little hard to understand. Basically the only time a friend "relation" or insertion into my database is made is if a user friends another user. So, if this relation is not in the database and in my query, I want to "let it go", so it doesn't just check for `friend_one` and `friend_two` relation.

```
$okay = true;

//Checks 
if ( $okay ) {
    $friend_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friend_one = ?
        AND friend_two = ?
    ";
    $select_friend_stmt = $con->prepare($friend_sql);
    $select_friend_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $profile_user));
    $friend_rows = $select_friend_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($friend_rows as $friend_row) {
        $select_friend_1 = $friend_row['friend_one'];
        $select_friend_2 = $friend_row['friend_two'];
        $friend_status = $friend_row['status'];
        $friend_status_date = $friend_row['date'];
    }
}
else {
    echo "Friend Status not found.";
}
$friend_status_button = null;
if ($friend_status == 2) {
    $friend_status_button = "Approved";
}
else if ($friend_status == 1) {
        $friend_status_button = "Pending";
}
else if ($select_friend_1 == $select_friend_2) {
    $friend_status_button = null;
}
else {
    $friend_status_button = "Add Friend";
}
```

Comment: Why not check to see if `$user_id ==  $profile_user`, and then bypass this whole code of checking if they are 'friends' with themselves.

Comment: @Sean Good idea, but as I was writing out the question I realized that any non-relation user will still throw an error for my query. So, I think it is more of a situation to check if `$profile_user` is not in the database to allow the query to run.... but I still need to check if `$user_id == $profile_user`, like you pointed out. It is a combination of my query and the two things I just pointed out...just can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: In php you can set a default for `$friend_status` (ie. `$friend_status = 0;`), that is only changed if a row is returned. That way it won't error on `if ($friend_status == ...`.  OR if you want to always return a row from MySQL, you can do a `UNION` with default row values - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3417312/689579

Comment: @Sean It is throwing an error because my `WHERE` clause. The values are not being found in my database, so my echoed values are not being created. That is what I am trying to solve. To allow this to run without the values being in the db.

Answer (score 0):

If It would be me, I would change the select statement

Editing my statement since your parameter is a question mark (?)

```
 SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friend_one = ?
        AND friend_two = ? and (friend_one <> ? and friend_two <> ?)
```

You're next problem would be the return value, since this would return null. So, I would check `$friend_rows` data, if it is equal to zero, then catch the error.

Comment: This just gave column not found errors. I used my initial query, just added `and (friend_one <> self and friend_two <> self)` to it.

Comment: let me point out sir that `self` should be your parameter, in your above case, it would be ?.

Comment: May I ask, is your parameter really a question mark?